# Can one throw out a Menorah?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia, disposal

Is it an issue to discard a menorah that has been used for the mitzvah of Neros Chanuka?

What if the menorah is made from something not usually used for a menorah? For example,[bottles](http://cdn.walyou.com/wp-content/uploads//2010/12/chanuka-menorah-vodka-bottles.jpg), [cans](http://sagharboronline.com/sagharborexpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/web-MENORAH-TEMPLE-ADAS-ISRAEL-300-MED-res.jpg), potatoes, [ice](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_r4euWFrN66Y/TP6JrLglWoI/AAAAAAAAAVI/-HgzYnl7OO8/s1600/chabad+ice+menorah.jpg)?

Comment: I've seen people in yeshiva who forgot to bring a menorah from home use inverted Styrofoam cups, donuts (!), and bananas (!!!) for lack of a better alternative.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[*Mishna B'rura* to 21:1](http://www.mishnaberura.com/Print.asp?NoPrint=True&SeifID=136) says that once a thing used for a *mitzva* is no longer usable for the *mitzva*, it can be discarded, but should not be discarded in a degrading manner or used for a degrading purpose. He considers deliberately throwing it onto the garbage heap as an example of discarding it in a degrading manner. [I've heard recommended that such an object be put in a separate bag and then in the garbage.] [However, see comments to this answer regarding whether a *m'nora* is included in this category.]

[As I wrote, he only says this about something used for a *mitzva* and no longer usable. I conjecture that his not considering a still-usable object is simply because such things aren't generally discarded at all, but that, if *bal tashchis* is not an issue, the same rule will apply.]

[As Double AA notes in his answer, this does not apply to things like *m'zuzos* and *t'filin*.]

As always, for practical matters, consult your rabbi rather than relying on what you read here.

Comment: Thinking some more: Do you have evidence that a Menora is ever considered Tashmishei Mitzva? The Mishna Berura is referring to a specific category of objects, not just anything that was ever used for a mitzva (eg, the plate I ate Seuda Shelishit on last week). I know I can't prove it isn't from my answer's kol vachomer (because of dayo) but I wonder...

Comment: Well, at least [this sourceless website](http://www.mazornet.com/holidays/Chanukah/menorah-disposal.htm) agrees with me.

Comment: @DoubleAA, good point. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 23):

You may discard it. The gemara ([Megillah 26b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=26b&format=pdf)) states:

> תנו רבנן: תשמישי מצוה - נזרקין, תשמישי קדושה - נגנזין. ואלו הן תשמישי מצוה: סוכה, לולב, שופר, ציצית. ואלו הן תשמישי קדושה: דלוסקמי ספרים, תפילין ומזוזות, ותיק של ספר תורה, ונרתיק של תפילין ורצועותיהן
>   Our Rabbis taught: ‘Accessories of religious observances [when disused] are to be thrown away; accessories of holiness are to be stored away. The following are accessories of religious observances: a sukkah, a lulab, a shofar, fringes. The following are accessories of holiness: large sacks for keeping scrolls of the Scripture in, tefillin and mezuzoth, a mantle for a sefer torah, and a tefillin bag and tefillin straps’. (Translation from [here](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Megilah.pdf))

A menorah is certainly in the former category, especially considering you don't actually need a menorah as you could light candles directly on a table! (Although see discussion [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22603/759).)

Comment: I am curious as to why a menorah is "certainly" in the former category if a tefillin bag is in the latter.

Comment: @sah tefilliin bags service tefilin. Menoras service candles. Candles don't have the sanctity of tefilin