# Throwing things out "respectfully"

Tags: halacha, kavod, disposal

I have heard many times that when something used for or somehow related to a mitzvah cannot or will not be used again, it should be thrown out "respectfully".

1. What exactly constitutes throwing out something respectfully and is it different depending on what is being thrown out?
2. Should something that is not technically a tashmish kedusha/ tashmish mitzva/ tashmish d'tashmish but is other wise associated with a mitzvah be thrown out respectfully?

(I am asking this because my tefilin bag* was worn out so I bought a new one to replace it. If you could include what I should do with that specifically in your answer it would be appreciated.)

*The plastic bag, not the cloth one.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12183/759

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14446/759

Comment: Please CYLOR regarding your tefilin bag and don't rely on anything written here.

Comment: I'm not anyone's LOR, but FWIW, I actually have a worn-out tallis-bag plastic sitting in the garbage bin in my room at this minute. My understanding is that only the actual bag which holds the tefillin are classified as "tashmishei kedusha." In the case of a tallis bag protector, it's three degrees removed from the tefillin - not even a "tashmish d'tashmish" - so I don't think there is any problem with disposing of it.

Comment: @Dave, I wonder though about the plastic bag the asker is asking about. It's there to protect not the cloth bag (who cares if the cloth bag gets wet) but the _t'filin_ themselves (as water can get through the cloth bag). I'd guess it's a _tashmish_ of the _t'filin_, which are themselves (IIRC) a _tashmish_ of the _parashiyos_. But as DoubleAA notes, nothing on this site should be relied on in practice!

Comment: AriA, note that a _tashmish k'dusha_ and a _tashmish mitzva_ are different. The former is something used for, e.g., a _sefer Tora_, like the cloth/box a _sefer Tora_ is in; the latter is something used for a _mitzva_, like _tzitzis_. If whatever answer you get doesn't mention this difference, read it carefully to determine which class of objects it's dealing with.

Comment: @msh210 - that's a good point, regarding the plastic bag serving as a direct protector of the tefillin with respect to water hazards. Though my feeling is that it's mostly intended to shield the cloth bag from getting stained and shredded.

Comment: I thought the plastic bag was just there because you shouldn't put things other than tfilin in the tfilin bag.

Comment: @AriA - I think that's only a secondary use that developed once plastic protectors became available. In the olden (pre-plastic) days, did everyone have a second cloth bag in which to put their other items? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/475304/jewish/Proper-Disposal-of-Holy-Objects.htm

> Mitzvah Objects:
>
> Objects in this category must be disposed of in a respectable manner;
>   **e.g. double wrapped in paper or plastic before being put in the
>   garbage.**
>
> Included in this category are such things as:
>
> The garments of a tallit or tzitzit (after the fringes have been
>   removed for burial), tallit bags, the Four Species, willows used for
>   hoshanot, schach (foliage covering for a sukkah), and a gartel (prayer
>   sash).

Comment: It's way late to point this out, but the section you quoted addresses a *tallit bag*, but the question is about a *tefillin bag*.  The article includes those in  the "Holy Objects" section.