# How does one dispose of Tzitzis?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tallit-katan, disposal

I was always told that if a single string falls off your *Tzitzis* you should put it in a *Sefer* so that it will end up in *Shamis*. My question is: Does anyone know a source for this?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/throwing-things-out-respectfully

Comment: duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14446/759

Comment: MB 21:8 brings the custom to use it as a bookmark.

Comment: As @DoubleAA points out, the part of this question that asks what to do with the _beged_ is a duplicate of a previously-asked question. I'm going to cull that part of this question from it, reducing it to the part about the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mishnah Berurah writes that the Maharil recommended using old tzitzis as a bookmark or for another mitzvah, because we have a rule in the Gemara that one should try to take an object used for a mitzvah and use it for another mitzvah ("*ho'il v'isavid b'hu mitzva chado, yisavid b'hu achariso*").

Your second question is addressed in the Shulchan Aruch, O.C. 21, 1-2. The *begged* can be thrown in the trash. Regarding the tzitzit, three opinions are presented: you can toss them in the trash, you should dispose of them in a more respectful manner (e.g. toss them in the bushes) or you should put them in *shaimmes*.

Comment: According to the Aruch haShulchan, the Rema's Yesh Omrim not to dispose of them in a disgraceful manner is not an alternate opinion to the Shulchan Aruch's throwing them out, but a qualification that even acc. to the Shulchan Aruch one must dispose of them properly.  His proof is from the beged, which is a lower mitzva, and the Shulchan Aruch says clearly one must not do anything disrespectful to them: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=45