# What is the proper way to dispose of Tzizit?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

Can I put old Tzizit (beged Katan or Gadol) in the garbage or must they be disposed of in a more respectful way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one dispose of Tzitzis?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17395/how-does-one-dispose-of-tzitzis)

Comment: @Shokhet That's about strings, I think?

Comment: I'm not sure what this question was asking, but it seems we covered both, @DoubleAA.