# Is there an imperative to have a fancy menorah?

Tags: mitzvah, menora-chanukia, holy-objects

Is it considered a meritorious practice to have a fancy/expensive/large menorah? Normally the imperative to beautify mitzvos is related to the mitzvah item itself (e.g. talis, tefillin, esrog), so here I would assume it would mean to have beautiful candles.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, note that opinions brought in Avnei Nezer 2:500 that you need to have the candles lit in some sort of *kli* (vessel) and not just loose. According to these opinions, the menora itself is a mitzva object.

That said, even if you don't rule that way we have a notion of hiddur mitzva even for things that aren't direct mitzva objects such as the quill used to write *Sta"m* (Shabbat 133b).

The Mishna Berura (673 sk 28) does note that one should expend effort to have as nice a menorah as one can.

Comment: The one page that's missing on Hebrewbooks: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1344&st=&pgnum=572

Comment: @ba I know :( I tried earlier. Isn't there a way to report that to them or something?

Comment: If you have the teshuva in front of you could you write down what his reasoning is for this? I wrote down this teshuva by me last year in regards to a different shailo that I had (maybe I'll post it here.)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that we likely do not pasken like this Avnei Nezer -- see for instance the Mishneh Berurah 671:18 and the Aruch HaShulchan 673:6

Comment: @Curiouser Avnei Nezer is essentially contemporary to those sources. See also Rivevot Efraim [1:434:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&pgnum=343) who seems to treat not having a menorah as a bedieved.

Comment: @Curiouser I saw in Nefesh HaRav over Shabbat that Rav Soloveitchik ruled strongly against the Avnei Nezer.

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't say they weren't contemporary; I said we likely do not pasken like him, since the main seforim from which we do typically pasken rule against him. I don't really understand how citing a tshuva or two is supposed to be meaningful against both the MB and AhS. Do you have some reason to believe that psak follows the Avnei Nezer on this?

Comment: @Curiouser Well I cited the Rivevot Ephraim. Also we typically rule like the MB and/or AhS when they rule regarding specific opinions. They never saw this Teshuva of the Avnei Nezer so we don't really know what they would have said (particularly the MB who I guess would have said טוב להחמיר whereas the AhS probably would have said לא שמענו מזה).

Comment: @DoubleAA It wasn't the Avnei Nezer's chiddush. The Avnei Nezer himself was only citing the Chesed l'Avraham. And it is based on diyukim in Rishonim. So the fact that the MB and AhS didn't see the Avnei Nezer is meaningless.  And the Rivevos Efraim does not seem to me to treat it as b'dieved; just the opposite based on his concluding sentence. So I would say you have no evidence that we pasken against the MB and AhS. And it's not like they were silent on the matter. They ruled explicitly.

Comment: @DoubleAA, As I am not able to look it up myself right now, can you tell me if it's patently clear that the Avnei Nezer means that all the candles need to share a utensil (like a Menorah), and not that each candle ought to be supported and stabilized with some sort of utensil, as opposed to, say, melting the wax base and securing it to some surface? (Obviously this would only work for a solid-state candle like wax.)

Comment: @SethJ His proof has to do with the avoda of hatavat haneirot in the mikdash whereby he proves that "הכלי בכלל הנר". So I don't know that they have to share the same utensil, but that each must be contained within a utensil. He even starts discussing what counts as a Keli based on Rambam Hilchot Keilim.

Comment: @DoubleAA, so a [beer-bottle Menorah](http://blogs.denverpost.com/beer/files/2011/12/Beer-Menorah-495x364.jpg) works according to him?

Comment: @SethJ כנלע"ד .

Comment: @Curiouser I guess my main point is that we are not bound to paskin against him, and any posek worth his salt could still choose to paskin that way if he wanted to.

Comment: A single *kli*, as opposed to, say, 8 candlesticks lined up on your windowsill?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I do not think that was his implication, but I haven't looked at it in a while. I think he was opposing 8 __candles__ lined up on your windowsill

Comment: I think you may be able to provide a better answer to [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50708/5323) :)

Answer (score 2):

Meseches Sofrim 20 seems to imply as much.

> One may not light an old lamp; one who only has an old lamp may whiten it well in fire, and that is permitted.

cf [this lecture](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/822003/Rabbi_Mordechai_Torczyner/Hiddur_vs-_%CE%BA%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82-_Chanukah-s_Competing_Concepts_of_Beauty#) (around the 22 min mark)