# Rambam in Mitzvah of Ner Channukah: why "Shemen and Neros"?

Tags: chanuka, rambam, menora-chanukia

The Rambam writes in Hilchos Channukah Perek 4 Halacha 12:

> אפילו אין לו מה יאכל אלא מן הצדקה שואל או מוכר כסותו ולוקח שמן ונרות ומדליק

What is the reason the Rambam wrote to take "Shemen and Neros" to light? Seemingly he could have just written "Shemen" or "Neros".

[It was recently pointed out in a question/answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22602/is-there-an-imperative-to-have-a-fancy-menorah) the shita of the Evnei Nezer that there is a din "cli" by the Channukah candles. Perhaps this Rambam is coming to also say that one needs to use a cli.

Comment: just taking a simplistic approach, if you accept that one can be yotzei through either, and you only list one, it might make someone think "well, I usק the other, therefore I am not beholden to go to such extremes to light" or maybe he is saying that you can use whichever is cheaper and are not required to get either one specifically.

Comment: Yes, that diyuk was recorded already in the tshuva on the topic in שו"ת עטרת פז חלק א כרך ב - יורה דעה סימן ז. But what is your question? It seems like you have answered it already...

Comment: @Curiouser To know if this diyuk is "correct" or if someone speaks about it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Curiouser Doesn't seem to be on Hebrew Books. Where can I find the teshuva?

Comment: @Yehoshua, I think this is a non-issue. Long ago, "ner" meant a lamp, which is to say a device that you would put oil into to light with a wick. It did not come to mean some solid-state object that was itself flammable ... until that type of thing (wax candles, eg.) became widely used.

Comment: @SethJ Could be. This is why I am asking what he means (if there is any "chiddush" here.) Ner usually would suffice to use by itself (lashon of chazal in many places in referring to a candle -- why then does he need to say "shemen" also...) Another way of looking at it.

Comment: @Yehoshua "lashon of chazal in many places in referring to a candle" Name one such place.