# Can you use a stolen menorah?

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing, menora-chanukia, lighting

Has a person fulfilled the obligation of lighting Chanukah candles if he uses a stolen menorah but owns the candles, match etc.?

Comment: Why would you think you have not fulfilled the obligation?

Comment: @DoubleAA You can't perform the mitzvah of lulav with a stolen lulav. Perhaps the OP considered it similar.

Comment: @Scimonster Perhaps? It would be nice if he would just tell us so we wouldn't have to guess how best to address his concerns...

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer but just my impression. I am assuming that the underlying concern is one of mitzvah haba b'aveira, a mitzvah whose performance comes about through the commission of a sin.

In the case of Channukah candles, there is no requirement to use ANY menorah
http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2789

so if I can be mekayem without **any** menorah, I can't imagine that the menorah can be considered the object through which I effect my kiyyum of the mitzvah, so its status as stolen seems immaterial. The aveirah (I would think) can prevent my kiyyum but not undo it.

Comment: Not all agree to that http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22603/759

Comment: @DoubleAA good point but is there a distinction between the "loose candles" cited in the Q you link to and the lashon of "attached" in the daily halacha site I linked to? If I melt the wax and attach the candle to a table is it "loose"?