# What may I do with the leftover lulav?

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim

Subject says it all.  Can I put it in the trash?

I plan to leave the Esrog in the china closet (like my grandmother did) which adds a nice aroma, all year.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12183/759